# css :first-visible-child & :last-visible-child

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm making a container with children.
I need the **first visible child** & **last visible child** have **rounded corners**.

My approach is using `:first-child` & `:last-child` and it works fine.
But if one/some children have `.hidden`, the layout seem broken.
So I need a something similar to `:first-visible-child` & `:last-visible-child`,
of course that selector doesn't exist. I need a **trick/hack** to archive the **similar result**.

Note: I cannot apply `border-radius` on the container with `overflow: hidden` because the child's box-shadow will be clipped out and the children might have *a shake transfom effect* and I don't want become clipped out.

Note: a javascript solution are welcome. Maybe using VisibilityObserver()

Here the illustration:
[image]

Comment: You will need JS for this, because of the way CSS selectors work actually doesn't let you achieve what you want: `:first-child.hidden` only selects an element that is BOTH the first child AND has the hidden class, not the first child that has the hidden class.

Comment: share your code to get answer to your specific case. There is not generic solution

Comment: Please share some code to support your question.

Comment: it just a flexbox with children.

Comment: *it just a flexbox with children.* --> so you can easily share it

Comment: `:nth-child(0n+1 of :not(.hidden))` => doesn't work 

Comment: here the sandbox you can modify: https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-border-radius-ewcmd